# Qt5 Connect Custom WindowClose Signal To A Different Window

Tags: c++, signals, connect, qt5, slots

I'm trying to connect a signal from one class to a slot in another class but when I do, my application crashes on startup. I read some other posts on here and the Qt forums that eluded to connecting custom signals as such but I think I'm connecting them wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

AdministrativeWindow.h

```
class AdministrativeWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit AdministrativeWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~AdministrativeWindow();

    private slots:
        void on_actionExit_Administrative_Window_triggered();

    private:
        Ui::AdministrativeWindow *ui;

    signals:
        void windowClose();
};
```

AdministrativeWindow.cpp

```
void AdministrativeWindow::on_actionExit_Administrative_Window_triggered()
{
    emit windowClose();
    close();
}
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
connect(adminWindow, SIGNAL(windowClose()), this, SLOT(adminWindowClose()));

void MainWindow::on_ConfigureUsersBtn_clicked()
{
    if(adminWindow == NULL)
    {
        adminWindow = new AdministrativeWindow();
        adminWindow->show();
    }
    else if(adminWindow->isVisible())
    {
        adminWindow->activateWindow();
        adminWindow->showNormal();
    }
    else
    {
        adminWindow->show();
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_adminWindowClose()
{
    delete adminWindow;
    adminWindow = NULL;
}
```

Comment: there is no need for private slots, all slots are public

Comment: where is adminWindowClose definition?

Comment: do a connect after pointer has been initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that you're using valid `adminWindow` pointer on connect:

```
void MainWindow::on_ConfigureUsersBtn_clicked()
{
    if(adminWindow == NULL)
    {
        adminWindow = new AdministrativeWindow();
        connect(adminWindow, SIGNAL(windowClose()), this, SLOT(adminWindowClose()));
        adminWindow->show();
    }
```

Comment: Ah, now I get this error after I moved the connect to on_ConfigureUsersBtn_clicked():

ASSERT failure in QWeakPointer: "Detected QWeakPointer creation in a QObject being deleted", file tools\qsharedpointer.cpp, line 1230
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.

Comment: I shoulod add that this doesn't occur until I trigger the close in the Admin window now, which is a better result than before because it would mean that the connect it (partially) working wouldn't it?

Comment: Don't worry, fixed it. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

be sure to do a connect after pointer has been initialized

```
connect(adminWindow, SIGNAL(windowClose()), this, SLOT(adminWindowClose()));
           ^
        valid ptr
```

also private slots are private if called as regular member functions but always public for connection. I think this is cleaner design to define slots as public since their purpose is communication and use private functions as usual when they are needed unless you really need such mixed concept as `private slot` (it might exist however and one can imagine some special circumstances in which this might have sense, I assume this is not the case here)